# I want to load images from specific folder from internal storage, how to load images? as well as video too

Tags: android, image, video, gridview

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter  {
private File currentDir;
String SCAN_PATH;
File allFiles ;
private Context context;


public Integer[] images={

      //I want to load images here


};

public ImageAdapter(Context c){
    context = c;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return images.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return images[position];
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}
```

I want to load Images. I can simply add images using ID's but I want to load images from Internal/sd card storage.
I want to know how to add images

Answer (score 0):

```
Try loading images into imageview as bitmap  
try {
        File f=new File(filepath, "imagename.jpg"); // internal or external storage path 
        Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f));
            ImageView img=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgPicker);
        img.setImageBitmap(b);
    } 
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

Hope this may work!
```